# Write a SQL query that retrieves all distinct rows having the same value in a column where count of these rows is larger than 1

Tags: sql, count, distinct

Basically I need to find all the ids with more than 1 name

so the output should be

```
 (2,a)(2,b)(4,a)(4,b)(4,c)
```

id name

1 a

2 a

2 b

3 c

3 c

4 a

4 b

4 c

I got a query working

```
select * from (select distinct * from test) t group by t.id having count(*) > 1
```

But I think there might be a simpler solution, so yeah, is there a simply solution, if yes, what is it?  Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select
  Id,
  Name
FROM test 
Group By Id, Name
Having Count(Distinct(Name)) > 1
```

Comment: Thanx for the input, I tried it in Sybase, removing the name in group by works for me, thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple things you might try:

```
select id, name
from T
where exists (
  select * from T as Tcopy
  where Tcopy.id = T.id
  and Tcopy.name <> T.name
);

with IDmultipleNames(id) as (
  select id
  from T
  group by id
  having min(name) <> max(name)
)
  select id, name
  from T
  where T.id in (
    select id from IDmultipleNames
  )
```